# What will be time and complexity of given code

Tags: time-complexity, code-complexity

F(i, j) represents the maximum value the user
can collect from i'th coin to j'th coin.

```
F(i, j) = Max(Vi + min(F(i+2, j), F(i+1, j-1) ), 
              Vj + min(F(i+1, j-1), F(i, j-2) ))
```

As user wants to maximize the number of coins.

```
Base Cases
    F(i, j) = Vi           If j == i
    F(i, j) = max(Vi, Vj)  If j == i + 1
```

Comment: Please edit your code to make it more readable. And also share, what your current findings are.

Comment: This isn't code; it's a definition of a mathematical function. There are different algorithms which could compute this function, and they can have different time complexities.